# JPA - Performance with using multiple entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, seam, openjpa

My situation is:

- The code is not mine
- I have two kinds of database: one is Dad, one is Son.
- In Dad, I have a table to store JNDI name. I will look up Dad using JNDI, create entity manager, and retrieve this table.
- From these retrieved JNDI names, I will create multiple entity managers using multiple Son databases.

The problem is:

- Son have thousands of entities. It takes each Son database around 10 minutes to load all entities. If there is 4 Son databases, it will be 40 minutes.

My question:

- Suppose we already create an entity manager (ready to use), is there any way to speed up the creation of those entity managers after that (which only differs in connection)

Please look at the code below
For each Son JNDI:

```
Map<String, String> puSonProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
puSonProperties.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", sonJndi);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PUSon", puSonProperties);
```

PUSon - All of them use the same persistence unit

```
log.info("Verify entity manager for son: {0} - {1}", sonCode, 
         emSon.find(Son_configuration.class, 0) != null ? "ok" : "failed!");
```

This is the actual code where I guess the loading of all entities begins. 10 mins.

Comment: Look into second-level cache in Hibernate (if you are using Hibernate).  However, what you said is rather conflicting, u said there are 4 Son DB. For each DB, it is normally represented by 4 EMF instead of EM.  For things from different DB/EMF, it is meant to be different, you shouldn't and unreasonable to share entities.  Moreover, why are you loading "ALL entities"?  I doubt if what u want is really JPA...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean there are 4 sonJndi, so the code above, emf is actually for each Son database, not for all. About the "loading all entities", that my guess because it run there for 10 mins. The code is not mine so I think that the owner create a small query there to trigger an action to load all entities. These code actually run on start up, so he want to load all entities before the user login

Comment: If it is the case, the short answer is: what you want to do is not reasonable.  It is not reasonable to share entities between emf as different emf is logically meaning different persistence store, and entities in them are meant to be different.  I believe you may want to revisit your design.  If you think you can share, then I believe you shouldn't treat them as different entities, or you should put your shared entities in their own context

Comment: I think this is the same with Multi tenant architecture, where we give each tenant a database instead of a tenantId with each row. As I said, I can't modify this code. Maybe I should rephrase my question like this: suppose we already create an entity manager (ready to use), is there any way to speed up the creation of those entity managers after that (which only differs in connection).

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the design. EntityManagers are not designed to work this way, they should be rather short-lived (eg. EM per transaction as it is often done). As you noticed loading a lot of entities will slow down EM a lot, because it is caching all objects. And it's not quite clear why you have to load all entities at a time. Wouldn't it be enough if EM loads an entity on-demand, only when it's really necessary?